# create-react-app --template typescript doesn't work

Tags: typescript, npm, create-react-app, npx

When I run the command

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

only a JS project is created, no `.tsx` file whatsoever.

- According to the [CRA's TS guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/), the command needs `react-scripts@2.1.0` or higher.
- But the version listed in `my-app`'s `package.json` is only `0.9.5`.
- And the globally installed version is `react-scripts@5.0.0`, which is latest.

My environment:

- Node 16.13.2 (installed with [this guide](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md))
- npm 8.4.1
- npx 5.0.0
- Xubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a **very** old copy of `create-react-app` installed globally, so `npx` is using that one rather than the latest. To remove it, use:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then `npx create-react-app` will pick up the latest one, which should handle that command line correctly.

*(I tested this by installing an old version globally, then using `npx` and sure enough, it was the old version that ran. I installed v1.0.0 and indeed, it didn't do anything with the `--template` argument. But even* it *installed `react-scripts` v5.)*